# How to set up vba code for only one sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently stuck trying to build a button that will run a sumifs macro. I am trying to build the button in `Sheet1` and have the sumifs execute on `Sheet2`. What I currently have is:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sumifs()
    Dim Sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim EndRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim SumRange As Range
    Dim CrtA As Range
    Dim CrtB As Range

    With Sht1
        EndRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Set Sht2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set SumRange = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("L5:L10")
    Set CrtA = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C5:C10")
    Set CrtB = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("K5:K10")

    For i = 5 To EndRow
        sht2.Cells(i, 4) = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(SumRange, crtA, Range("G" & i), crtB, Range("B" & i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

I have tried running it with `alt + F8` and it works great as long as I am in `Sheet2`, if I try running it on `Sheet1` nothing happens.

Also, is there a way to link the sumifs criteria to a separate worksheet? Specifically, I am trying to have `Range ("B" & 1)` be linked to a cells `J5:J10` on `Sheet3`. Currently, I get a type error whenever I try

```
worksheets("sheet3").range ("B" & 1)
```

Really appreciate any advice you can provide.
Thanks

Comment: `Range("G" & i), crtB, Range("B" & i)`, you need to specify the sheet.

Comment: This is most likely a problem with fully qualified references. See this tutorial: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/referring_to_ranges_in_your_vba_code/

Answer (score 6):

Put the code in a module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SumIfS()
    Dim Sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim Sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim EndRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim SumRange As Range
    Dim CrtA As Range
    Dim CrtB As Range

    Set Sht2 = Worksheets(2)
    Set Sht1 = Worksheets(1)

    With Sht1
        EndRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Set SumRange = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("L5:L10")
    Set CrtA = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C5:C10")
    Set CrtB = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("K5:K10")

    For i = 5 To EndRow
        With Sht2
            .Cells(i, 4) = WorksheetFunction.SumIfS(SumRange, CrtA, .Range("G" & i), CrtB, .Range("B" & i))
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

The idea is that it is really a good practice to mention the "Parent-Worksheet" of the range. Otherwise it is taking either the `ActiveSheet` (if in a module) or the `worksheet` in which the code resides.

Whenever you are using construction like this:

```
With Sht1
    EndRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

You need to tell `VBA` to refer somehow to the `Sht1`. This is done, through dots here:

[image]

Otherwise it takes the Parent worksheet, which is either `ActiveSheet` or the one where the code is (if not in a module).