# Calling a user defined Function in Sub VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA. I am currently trying to apply a loop on a user defined function. 
The defined function is as follows.

```
  Function CountColor(InRange As range, ColorIndex As Long, _
    Optional OfText As Boolean = False) As Long
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' CountColor
' This function counts the cells in InRange whose ColorIndex
' is equal to the ColorIndex parameter. The ColorIndex of the
' Font is tested if OfText is True, or the Interior property
' if OfText is omitted or False. If ColorIndex is not a valid
' ColorIndex (1 -> 56, xlColorIndexNone, xlColorIndexAutomatic)
' 0 is returned. If ColorIndex is 0, then xlColorIndexNone is
' used if OfText is Fasle or xlColorIndexAutomatic if OfText
' is True. This allows the caller to use a value of 0 to indicate
' no color for either the Interior or the Font.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim R As range
Dim N As Long
Dim CI As Long

If ColorIndex = 0 Then
    If OfText = False Then
        CI = xlColorIndexNone
    Else
        CI = xlColorIndexAutomatic
    End If
Else
    CI = ColorIndex
End If


Application.Volatile True
Select Case ColorIndex
    Case 0, xlColorIndexNone, xlColorIndexAutomatic
        ' OK
    Case Else
        If IsValidColorIndex(ColorIndex) = False Then
            CountColor = 0
            Exit Function
        End If
End Select

For Each R In InRange.Cells
    If OfText = True Then
        If R.Font.ColorIndex = CI Then
            N = N + 1
        End If
    Else
        If R.Interior.ColorIndex = CI Then
            N = N + 1
        End If
    End If
Next R

CountColor = N


End Function
```

I am trying to use this function CountColor in a Sub. But it throws a runtime 424 error.

```
Sub Summary()    
    LastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LastRow
        TOTALFAILS = CountColor((range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, LastColumn))), 38)
        Cells(i, LastColumn + 8) = TOTALFAILS

        Next i
End Sub
```

Could you please help me figure out what am doing wrong? Any help will be deeply appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: In your loop, you are passing 2 range variables into your function. Your function requires a range, long, and an optional boolean. Are you trying to pass the value or the cell as the the ColorIndex? Or the color of the cell?

Comment: @Dude_Scott - actually `Range(Cells(i,4),Cells(i,LastColumn))` is 1 range parameter, not 2.

Comment: You’re right. I misread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one "(" more than needed in the way the function is called, thus it does not get the correct parameters. Try this:

```
CountColor(Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, LastColumn)), 38)
```

To make sure you are passing on the expected parameter, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, while on the line. The VBEditor would help:

[image]

In general, whenever working with `Range()` and `Cells()` objects, make sure to refer their Worksheets and Workbooks, [to avoid 1004 errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50758824/5448626). In the case of the example it should be like this:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        TOTALFAILS = CountColor(.Range(.Cells(i, 4), .Cells(i, LastColumn)), 38)
        .Cells(i, LastColumn + 8) = TOTALFAILS
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Upvoted for correctness. @RohinRaj see my answer for *why* this answer is correct.

Comment: @RohinRaj you'll get a +2 reputation bonus if you mark an answer as "accepted", by clicking the hollow green checkmark just underneath the up/down voting buttons next to either answer. Note that this will also take your question out of the "unanswered" questions list.

Answer (score 1):

Your `CountColor` function is expecting a `Range` object reference for the first parameter, but that's not what you're giving it:

```
TOTALFAILS = CountColor((range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, LastColumn))), 38)
```

The first argument is the result of this expression:

```
(range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, LastColumn)))
```

When you put an argument between parentheses, what you're passing is the evaluated result of the expression, passed `ByVal` (regardless of the function's signature specifying `ByRef` or not).

So why "object required" then? Doesn't the expression evaluate to a `Range` object?

The `Range` class has a hidden *default member* that you can reveal in the *Object Browser* (F2):

[image: Members of 'Range']

Notice the hidden/shaded `_Default` member.

If you're familiar with the `Collection` class, you might be aware of its `Item` member being that class' default member:

[image: Members of 'Collection']

The default member can be implicitly invoked. That's how you can do `myCollection("someKey")` to retrieve an item, and that's how it's completely equivalent to `myCollection.Item("someKey")`.

The `Range.[_Default]` member is a bit different, in that its implementation will "redirect" to different members, depending on context: when invoked without parameters, it returns `Range.Value` - for a single-cell range, that's the cell's value. For a multiple-cell range, that's a 2D variant array containing all the values.

So when you pass `(someRange)` as an argument, what you're implicitly passing is `(someRange.[_Default])`, *because* the class has a default, parameterless member (well, the two parameters are optional, so a parameterless invocation is legit).

In other words you're passing a 2D variant array to `CountColor` - not a `Range` object reference.

And that's why VBA throws run-time error 424 "object required" - because the call requires an object, but no object was provided.

[As Vityata already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55051602/1188513), removing the extraneous parentheses will fix this, because without the extraneous parentheses, you're no longer forcing `ByVal` evaluation of the `Range` object/expression.

Comment: Note: the object browser doesn't show hidden members by default. You need to right-click somewhere and tick the "show hidden members" option to have them show up.